# Matplotlib doesn't open Plotting window when ploting in a cycle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to **plot some data live** so I tried this simple example:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axis([0, 1000, 0, 1])
plt.ion()
plt.show()

for i in range(1000):
    print "in"
    y = np.random.random()
    plt.scatter(i, y)
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

The plotting window simply opens up, but nothing is ploted on it (the window actually stops responding). I notices it is indeed performing the for cycle since i can se the "in" print output

Comment: try ```plt.figure()``` before ```plt.draw()```

Comment: Hello @threxx , i did that but it actually doesnt work. Only a bunch of fempty pop up. If i indicate which figure to plot int (i.e. plt.figure(1)), still, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've met problems with Python3 with in-time drawing.
This should work for you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axis([0, 1000, 0, 1])
plt.ion()
plt.show()

for i in range(1000):
    print "in"
    y = np.random.random()
    plt.scatter(i, y)
    plt.pause(0.05)
```

Comment: The reason that `pause` works where as `sleep` does not is that `pause` runs the GUI event loop as well.

Comment: @tcaswell , what do you mean by " `pause` runs the GUI event loop as  well "